# Elementor Not Loading On WordPress Subdirectory Installation With Composer

Tags: wordpress, composer-php, http-status-code-404, assets, elementor

## WordPress in its own directory using Composer

### Troubleshooting Elementor Infinite Loading Screen

Inspired by [roots/bedrock](https://roots.io/bedrock/), I started a project to install WordPress to its own subdirectory using Composer. Plugins and Themes are installed from WPackagist, separately from the core WordPress files, also using Composer.

I ran into an issue with Elementor, which was stupid simple to fix. However, when I was in the process of fixing it, my Stack Overflow query,  'wordpress composer “elementor” -visual', returned nothing interesting. So I set out to write a quick troubleshooting guide for my own oversight. I have been obsessed with using Composer for WordPress dependencies lately, so I'm excited to write about it.

Anyway, after setting up the WordPress core and plugins using Composer, and setting up my database credentials in wp-config, I can login to the dashboard just fine.

### Here's the Issue

In the dashboard, I see an issue immediately; the Elementor icon is missing, showing a generic gear instead. Here is the first clue that Elementor cannot find its own assets.

Furthermore, when I try to create a new page in Elementor, I see only an infinite, white Loading screen. Additionally, the "Edit with Elementor" button is missing when creating new posts and pages.

### Initial Debugging Methods

1. Turn on PHP debugging in wp-config.php -> Revealed nothing enlightening.
2. Remove all other plugins besides Elementor -> No changes.
3. Turn on Safe Mode in Elementor > Tools -> Revealed nothing enlightening.

***What next?***

I will tell you how I fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

### Developer Console Insights

To finally resolve this issue, I opened the developer console (CTRL+SHIFT+I) and inspected some of the 404 links in the Network tab. An issue was immediately apparent: the filepath was incorrect. My project's folder is called "subdir-wp-elementor", not "subdir-wordpress".

Here is what Elementor was trying (and failing) to load:

http://localhost/**subdir-wordpress**/app/plugins/elementor/assets/js/editor-modules.min.js?ver=2.9.12

### Resolution: Update CONTENT_URL in wp-config

I realized that I had forgotten to update the CONTENT_URL definition in wp-config.php

My SITE_URL was http://localhost/subdir-wp-elementor/, but here was my CONTENT_URL:

```php
// ========================
// Custom Content Directory
// ========================
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/app' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/subdir-wordpress/app' );
```

Setting the correct CONTENT_URL to the below allowed Elementor to properly load.

```php
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/subdir-wp-elementor/app' );
```